# Olf Futaba Rx & Tx with APM micro 2.7.2?

Tags: quadcopter

Hi there I just found this old Rx & Tx in my loft and need to know weather it is compatible with my APM micro 2.7.2. I already have telemetry but that does not give me manual control. My guess is I need a new Rx because the current one will make a hash of the electronics on the APM. Thanks in advance[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image descriptere][2]][2]

[image]

[image]